# Cómo puedo mostrar en una consulta de MySQL campos solo cuando ellos tengan información

Tags: mysql

Necesito generar una consulta en MySQL la cual me saque información de diferentes campos pero solo los muestre si su valor es mayor a '0', de lo contrario no formen parte del resultado de dicha consulta.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido. No tienes nada de código? Este es un ejemplo de una consulta `SELECT * FROM miTabla WHERE campoNumero>0`.  Puedes ver más info aquí. Por favor edita tu pregunta con lo que haz logrado hasta el momento.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tienes que hacer es esto.

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myColumn > 0;
```

Puedes agregar otras cláusulas

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myColumn1 > 0 AND myColumn2 = 'something';
```

Puedes elegir los campos a mostrar en tu resultado.

```
SELECT myColumn1,myColumn2, myColumn5  
FROM myTable aliasesFromTable 
WHERE myColumn1 > 0 AND myColumn2 = 'something';
```